# How do you use $_GET with URLs?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website similar to Facebook. Users can view other profiles. And navigate through their info, "wall", and photos just like on Facebook.

I am having trouble trying to understand `$_GET`. here is my problem:

I am trying to use `$_GET` to display the data for the user being viewed.

I know I use a key name and `$_GET` in my SQL query. Like:

```
$query = "SELECT FROM table name, lastname WHERE $_GET['user_Id']";
```

I know if I type the URL as `www.example.com/profile.php?user_id=1` then it displays that profile.

Now what do I make the link if I want there to be the links like stated earlier?

Do I do?

```
<a href="www.example.com/profile.php?user_id=1&action=wall">
```

then I set the `if` statements and functions
And what not, I know how to do that.

```
Switch
Case 'wall'
Function display_wall()
Echo ("whatever code")
```

Now when the user hits the info link, does the browser just keep the `$_GET['user_id']` set to what it was on the profile.php page?

Comment: I think you need to learn basics first before doing anything with a database...

Comment: You should read up on SQL injection.

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable and sql injection can be performed easily. On `$_GET` variable - it's set fresh for every http GET request.

Comment: Just for info, never use $_GET directly in a query! $_GET depends on user input. You have to sanitize this input before using it. Otherwise, it will just be a pleasure for SQL injection fanboys...

Comment: So how do I store the users Id from profile.php?user_id=1 to profile.php?user_id=&action=wall ?

Comment: You can use sessions if you want to have some persistent state between client and server (see $_SESSION variable in php).

Comment: Hmm a session works for you own profile. What about viewing others? And navigating through their wall and info and what not? How do I make sure the $_GET['user_Id'] stays set as the user you are viewing?

Comment: and learn basics before doing anything like facebook

Comment: @user502019: It's better to just always include the user_id in the URL, relying on sessions can get buggy.

Comment: @animuson: I must agree - avoid using session data if you can. Your interface should be as stateless as possible.

Answer (score 5):

**Sanitize user input!**

Please, sir, don't do this:

```
$query= SELECT FROM table name, lastname WHERE $_GET['user_Id']
```

It's very unsafe. I highly suggest you to sanitize every user input (that includes GET and POST) before using it into SQL queries. That script is SQL-Injection vulnerable, and it can be exploited very easily.

**How to use GETs**

Yes you have to set

```
<a href="www.example.com/profile.php?user_id=1&action=wall">
```

The browser doesn't remember GET and POST. GET can only be attached to the URL, so that you have to keep repeating `?user_id=1` to every page if you need `$_GET['user_id']`.

What you have wrote (`<a href="www.example.com/profile.php?user_id=&action=wall">`) will set `$_GET['user_id']` = ''.

**Cookie and session**

If you want to store data from page to page based on which user is viewing the page just set a cookie or start an user session. You can read about them on Google.

**Switch in PHP**

Olso the switch thing is wrong. That's how to use switch in PHP:

```
switch {
    case 'wall':
        display_wall();
        echo "whatever code";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you use the entity in the anchor though, `& => &amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're working on a big project and my answer is probably not going to help a ton, but here goes.  `$_GET` is an array comprised of variables from the URL.  In your example of:

```
<a href="www.example.com/profile.php?user_id=&action=wall>
```

`$_GET['user_id']` would return nothing since you said `?user_id=`  (and then nothing)
`$_GET['action']` would return 'wall'

You can also you the `$_POST` variable which will give you data that you've specified on a form.

Just be careful when using `$_GET` to not simply inject that string into your SQL.  This can cause bad things to happen (look up SQL injection).

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: So do I then say profile.php?user_Id=$variable&action=wall. Then state in my script that.       $variable=$_GET['user_id']